# Azure Mobile Client: Conflict Handling UPDATE Operation error.Result == null

Tags: azure-mobile-services

In my Conflict Handling code occacionally it happens that the `error.Result` is `null` in case of an **UPDATE** operation and I don't know why or what causes that.

That is my code:

```
 private async Task HandleConflictResolutionOfLocalTablePushAttemptAsync(ReadOnlyCollection<MobileServiceTableOperationError> syncErrors)
        {
            /*
             * * Handling Conflict Resolution

             * * see :https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/client/#handling-conflict-resolution
             * * */


            // Simple error/conflict handling. A real application would handle the various errors like network conditions,
            // server conflicts and others via the IMobileServiceSyncHandler.
            if (syncErrors != null)
            {
                foreach (var error in syncErrors)
                {
                    var localItem = error.Item;
                    var serverItem = error.Result;

                    if (error.OperationKind == MobileServiceTableOperationKind.Update && error.Result != null)
                    {
                        var localVersion = localItem?[MobileServiceSystemColumns.Version];
                        var serverVersion = serverItem?[MobileServiceSystemColumns.Version];

                        if (localVersion == null)
                        {
                            if (await IsRemoteBackendReachable())
                            {
                                //Update failed, reverting to server's copy.
                                await error.CancelAndUpdateItemAsync(serverItem);

                                await MetricsManagerHelper.Instance
                                    .SendErrorToApplicationInsightsAsync($"Operation: {error.OperationKind} LocalVersion == NULL." +
                                                                         "Action: Reverting to remote-db server's copy\r\n" +
                                                                         $"Table: {error.TableName} Record Id: {localItem?[MobileServiceSystemColumns.Id]}\r\n" +
                                                                         $"Local: {localItem}\r\n" +
                                                                         $"Server: {serverItem}");
                            }

                            continue;
                        }


                        if (serverVersion == null)
                        {
                            if (await IsRemoteBackendReachable())
                            {
                                //Update failed, reverting to server's copy.
                                await error.CancelAndUpdateItemAsync(serverItem);

                                await MetricsManagerHelper.Instance
                                    .SendErrorToApplicationInsightsAsync($"Operation: {error.OperationKind} ServerVersion == NULL.\r\n" +
                                                                         "Action: Reverting to remote-db server's copy\r\n" +
                                                                         $"Table: {error.TableName} Record Id: {localItem?[MobileServiceSystemColumns.Id]}\r\n" +
                                                                         $"Local: {localItem}\r\n" +
                                                                         $"Server: {serverItem}");
                            }

                            continue;
                        }


                        // Set Local version to Server Version an Update again. PendingOpertation is set to new updated localItem and in outer loop a PushAsync is attempted again.
                        localItem[MobileServiceSystemColumns.Version] = serverItem[MobileServiceSystemColumns.Version];

                        if (await IsRemoteBackendReachable())
                        {
                            await error.UpdateOperationAsync(JObject.FromObject(localItem));
                            await MetricsManagerHelper.Instance.SendInfoToApplicationInsightsAsync($"Operation: {error.OperationKind} LocalVersion older than (<) ServerVersion. LocalItem updated in local.db.");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (await IsRemoteBackendReachable())
                        {
                            // Discard local change.
                            await error.CancelAndDiscardItemAsync();

                            await MetricsManagerHelper.Instance
                                .SendErrorToApplicationInsightsAsync($"Operation: {error.OperationKind} PUSH failed.\r\n" +
                                                                     "Action: Discard local-db change.\r\n" +
                                                                     $"Table: {error.TableName} Record Id: {localItem?[MobileServiceSystemColumns.Id]}\r\n" +
                                                                     $"Local: {localItem}\r\n" +
                                                                     $"Server: {serverItem}");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

In case when `error.Result` is `null` I have no other option than discarding the localItem changes.

Can you explain me when it can happen that `error.Result` is `null`? 
The only reasonable guess I have is that the intenet connection is lost and no serverItem can be retrieved. But immediatly before I call the conflict handler I check if my remote backend is reachable.

Thanks in advance

Eric

Comment: I don't think that's the case.  More likely, something else (a 500, perhaps) was received.  What does the rest of the error look like?  What is the underlying error?  What does the backend say in verbose logging?

Comment: Thanks for setting me on the right trail. I will log all on client/server and get back.